# Retrieve Image in different Size from Database

Tags: java, database, image

I have stored some images in database, while retrieving them i want to resize it to 177x122. How can i do that in JAVA?
Here is some code that i have used to retrieve image from database, what changes need to be done to get a image of 177x122.

```
PreparedStatement pstm1 = con.prepareStatement("select * from image");
            ResultSet rs1 = pstm1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next()) {
                InputStream fis1;
                FileOutputStream fos;
                String image_id;
                try {
                    fis1 = rs1.getBinaryStream("image");
                    image_id=rs1.getString("image_id");
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("images" + (image_id) + ".jpg"));
                    int c;
                    while ((c = fis1.read()) != -1) {
                        fos.write(c);
                    }
                    fis1.close();
                    fos.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Successfully Retrieved");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the AWT provided BufferedImage and Graphics2D classes to resize your images.  [Source](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/)

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data in the `image` column is a image format that the Java Image I/O can read (such as JPEG and PNG), the [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) library should be able to achieve this.

The code which would retrieve the image data from the `ResultSet` as an `InputStream` and write to specified file can be written like this:

```
// Get the information we need from the database.
String imageId = rs1.getString("image_id");
InputStream is = rs1.getBinaryStream("image");

// Perform the thumbnail generation.
// You may want to substitute variables for the hard-coded 177 and 122.
Thumbnails.of(is)
  .size(177, 122)
  .toFile("images" + (imageId) + ".jpg");

// Thumbnailator does not automatically close InputStreams
// (which is actually a good thing!), so we'll have to close it.
is.close();
```

*(I should disclaim that I haven't actually run this code against an actual database.)*

Thumbnailator will read the image data from the `InputStream` retrieving binary data from the `image` column, then resize the image to fit into the 172 x 122 region, and finally output the thumbnail as a JPEG to the specified file.

By default, Thumbnailator will preserve the aspect ratio of the original image when resizing images (to prevent the thumbnail from looking distorted), so the image size will not necessarily be 172 x 122. If this behavior is undesirable, calling the `forceSize` method instead of the `size` method can achieve that.

*Disclaimer: I maintain the Thumbnailator library.*